# Trouble placing video behind a div element

Tags: html, css, html5-video

I'm trying to place a small video behind a banner-like div element. After some time researching I managed to at least show the contents of the div, but the video is nowhere to be seen. If I place them separately both show up, but if I try to stack them on top of each other it disappears.

HTML:

```
<div id="castle-siege">
    <div id="cs-video">
        <video id="videocs" width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="auto">
            <source src=/assets/img/cs.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        </video>
    </div>
    <div id="cs-table">
        //content
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#castle-siege {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#cs-video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 5;
}

#cs-table {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: please post the resulting html instead of the php code

Comment: done, sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in this instance, that you need to set `position` attribute as well as z index in order to display the video properly. Also ensure your video is present and correct at the set url of course! Set the position of the video to `absolute` and set the table `relative` to it, either with a higher or lower `z-index`, as necessary (higher if you want it to be seen on top of the video)

For purposes of demo, I set the width to 80%, it's prob better to use percentages/ an adjustable unit, rather than setting the width in px.

Hope this helps

```css
    #castle-siege {
      width: 80%;
      height: 150px;
      text-align: center;
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    #cs-video {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      position: absolute;
      z-index:0;
    }

    #cs-table {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      margin-top: 30px;
      margin-left: 50px;
      color:red;
      text-align:left;
      position: relative;
      z-index:1;
    }
```

```html
<div id="castle-siege">
  <div id="cs-video">
    <video id="videocs" width="100%" height="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" preload="auto">
      <source src="http://mirrors.standaloneinstaller.com/video-sample/jellyfish-25-mbps-hd-hevc.mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
  <div id="cs-table">
     Hi there, how's it going? There's supposed to be a table here.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'd advise to use the **full** url for your video source.. the relative url could be causing an issue.. are you sure it is correct?

Comment: setting video element position to absolute and the table relative to the video did the job, thank you!

Comment: @Kurisu Happy to help :)